# Как нарисовать анимированную 3D Линию через цикл в python?

Tags: python

**Дано:** 4 токчи в 3d системе, они следующие:

`P0(1,11,1)`
`P1(1,22,1)` `P2(MyX,MyY,MyZ)` `P3(11,1,11)`

**Задача вот такая**: Построить прямые по этим контрольным точкам через цикл в python, да вот так, что они бы по затее `MyX++,MyY++,MyZ++` в реальном времени меняли свои узловые точки, т.е. график был бы анимирован, согласно циклу `a=range(1,100)`... Задержка между обновлениями координат, например, `MyX++` - должна составлять: `250 мс`.
Я новичок в python, перешел на него с java, так что не ругайтесь матом, мне нужен примерчик.)

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)

x = [4, 4, 44, 9, 12, 24]
y = [34, 41, 78, 12, 23, 56]
# put 0s on the y-axis, and put the y axis on the z-axis
ax.plot(xs=x, ys=[0]*len(x), zs=y, zdir='z', label='ys=0, zdir=z')
plt.show()

print("a1")
```

Вот что я имею на данный момент. Но никак не могу вклинить сюда цикл с параметрами `MyP`.